# How To Get Current Page Parameters And Properties of Joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla

I want to create a module for joomla 3.1 for my own site. I need to know how to get current category id, parent category id, current page id. Please some one tell me how to do that. Thanks for your advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

going from memory here, please bear with some inaccuracies but it should be enough to get you going.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

// should be article, categories, featured, blog...
$view = $input->get('view'); 

// if it's a category view, this will be the category id, else the article id
$id = $input->getInt('id'); 

// in an article view, this will be the cat id.
$catid = $input->getInt('catid'); 

// this is the menu item id i.e. what you call page id I guess.
$Itemid = $input->getInt('Itemid');
```

Comment: It is work thanks.. by the way.. How I know when I can use "input" statement on $input variable or using another statement like what you have done. Thanks

Comment: Usually you can use the $input variable if you have defined it like I have at line 1 of the code. Otherwise it would be unassigned. I suggest you read more on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php